# Regex: how to extract only first IP address from string (in Python)

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string (or similar strings, some of which may contain more than one IP address):

```
from mail2.oknotify2.com (mail2.oknotify2.com. [208.83.243.70]) by mx.google.com with ESMTP id dp5si2596299pdb.170.2015.06.03.14.12.03
```

I wish to extract the first and only the first IP address, in Python. A first attempt with something like `([0-9]{2,}\.){3}([0-9]{2,}){1}` when tried out on nregex.com, looks *almost* OK, matching the IP address fine, but also matches the other substring which roughly resembles an IP address (170.2015.06.03.14.12.03). When the same pattern is passed to `re.compile/re.findall` though, the result is:

```
[(u'243.', u'70'), (u'06.', u'03')]
```

So clearly the regex is no good. How can I improve it so that it's neater and catches all IPV4 address, and how can I make it such that it only matches the first?

Many thanks.

Comment: Will the IP addresses always be within square brackets?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude yes for the purposes of this exercise I'm only checking "Received: from" headers, and from what I can tell, for these,the IP address is always contained in [].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `re.search` with the following pattern:

```
>>> s = 'from mail2.oknotify2.com (mail2.oknotify2.com. [208.83.243.70]) by mx.google.com with ESMTP id dp5si2596299pdb.170.2015.06.03.14.12.03'
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', s).group()
'208.83.243.70'
```

Comment: It may be prudent to ensure that the IP within the brackets are captured explicitly if that's the OPs desire: re.search(r'\\[(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\\]', s).group(1)

Answer (score 1):

The regex you want is `r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'`. This catches 4 1- to 4-digit numbers separated by dots.

If the IP number always comes before other numbers in the string, you can avoid selecting it by using a non-greedy function such as `re.find`. In contrast, `re.findall` will catch both `208.83.243.70` and `015.06.03.14`.

Are you OK with using the brackets to single out the IP number? if so, you can change the regex to `r'\[(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\]'`. It would be safer that way.

Comment: thanks. I don't see re having a function find. Were you referring to something else?