# How to find an IP pattern in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to find an IP pattern or any similar pattern in a string. for example:

> Text_1 = "Hello this ip is valid: 123.22.33.22  , but!" #expect 123.22.33.22
>
> Text_2 = "this could be the second valid ip: 323.123.22.33.22  , but!" #expect 323.123.22.33.22
>
> Text_3 = "third pattern is: 01.002.33.222  , but!" #expect 01.002.33.222
>
> Text_4 = "fourth pattern is: 332.332.222  , but!" #expect 332.332.222

In all cases I need to extract all numbers which are separate by dots and later on evaluate if they are potentially valid or not.

I had a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654285/regex-how-to-extract-only-first-ip-address-from-string-in-python?rq=1) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890896/how-to-extract-an-ip-address-from-an-html-string) question, but all have some issues!

This is what I found but does not work perfectly as it can't catch the string longer than 4-digit:

```
import re
re.search(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', s).group()
```

Comment: This is confusing as most of these are not valid IP addresses.

Comment: If you're just looking for dotted digit sequences, how about `\d+(\.\d+)*`?

Comment: Yes I am trying to extract these numbers to evaluate later if they are valid IP or not. Because none of solutions in aforementioned links do not give a valid solution to validate the IP, that's why I am trying to first extract numbers

Comment: `r"(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)"` ?

Comment: Are you sure you also need `323.123.22.33.22`?

Comment: @ I think this is not correct as I don't know the number of digits separated by dots in the input string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want *any* sequence of numbers and dots, try this:

```py
# Find a number, then one or more ".numbers"
re.search(r'(\d+)(\.(\d+))+', Text_2).group()
```

It gives:

```
'323.123.22.33.22'
```

**Note**: After extracting candidates, you can check it with the regex provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59435087/9414470).

Comment: @Readers, should I explain the regex more? Or some more examples? As it is, the answer may not be too useful...

Answer (score 0):

How about: map(int, “167.78.2.99”.split(“.”))) (split by . And try to convert each to an integer) and check for type error, check if len() is 4 and check for each element 0<=el<256.

Sorry for no code, not at my computer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how did you extract that 4-digits/5-digits/3-digits numbers from my provided strings?

Comment: Oops, did not read the question well enough, i guess you could use answer 1, or if you do not like re, split on spaces, go over each word and strip it of anything but numbers and use the code i gave.

Answer (score 0):

This finds exact ip addresses:

```
^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/3biYkC/1

Update, i added a word boundry to it, it seems to work:

```
\b(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/3biYkC/2

Comment: But how would it extract the IP address from the original string? This can be definitely applied _after_ extracting possible matches.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar True, I'll put some thought around it and make a new version that may find it anywhere.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar  check the second one out, it seems to work well. You can test more cases at the regex101 site

Comment: Lol. `-25.1.3.2` is being matched by ignoring the `-`. Should we check the minus in the regex as well?

Comment: lol, you could add a space after the \b to not match concatenated IP's touching other  things. idk, i'm sure some more work could be put to it.