# Python Regex - Replacing IP addresses

Tags: python, regex

I'm new in python and regex and I have been trying to hide the IP Address logs in a txt file. I should avoid using for loops and if checks -if possible because txt file is huge (158MB).

(All the IP addresses starts with 172)

This is the code i tried:

```
import re
txt = "test"
x = re.sub(r"^172\.*", "XXX.\", txt)
print(x)
```

Sample txt file:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRST172.12.65.10RSTUVYZ
ASDG172.56.23.14FSDGHSFSDFDSFHSF
!'^%%&!'+!'+^%&!ÂSDBSDF172.23.23.23SADASFSA
ASGFGD 172.12.23.56 ASDSAFASFDASSADSA
```

Desired output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTXXX.XXX.XXX.XXXRSTUVYZ
ASDGXXX.XX.XX.XXFSDGHSFSDFDSFHSF
!'^%%&!'+!'+^%&!ÂSDBSDFXXX.XXX.XXX.XXXSADASFSA
ASGFGD XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ASDSAFASFDASSADSA
```

Comment: ``re.sub(r'(172\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", text)``

Comment: Here is a dupe, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654313/4985099

Comment: Another question, in the declaration part I'm assigning "test" to txt variable as a String. However, I want to read it from the file what should I do?
I made it like:

txt = open("test.txt", "r+")
x = re.sub(r'(172\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})', "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", txt)

But it gives an type error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indeed use `re.sub`.

```
re.sub("(172)(\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}[0-9]{1,3})", r"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", tested_addr)
```

An explanation about the regex (You don't really need the groups for the for what you've requested but its a nice way to understand the parts of the regex:

`^(172)(\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}[0-9]{1,3})$`

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
1st Capturing Group (172)
172 matches the characters 172 literally (case sensitive)
2nd Capturing Group (\.(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}[0-9]{1,3})
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
Non-capturing group (?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){2}
{2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]{1,3}
{1,3} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]{1,3}
{1,3} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Comment: That's a nice regex, but, how do you replace with `xxx`?

Comment: @Toto Updated with a full solution

Comment: That doesn't give the expected result, (re)read the question.

Comment: @Toto Now it does

Answer (score 0):

Use: `172(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}`

**Code:**

```
string = r'''ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRST172.12.65.10RSTUVYZ
ASDG172.56.23.14FSDGHSFSDFDSFHSF
!'^%%&!'+!'+^%&!SDBSDF172.23.23.23SADASFSA
ASGFGD 172.12.23.56 ASDSAFASFDASSADSA'''

print re.sub(r'172(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}', "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", string)
```

**Output:**

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTXXX.XXX.XXX.XXXRSTUVYZ
ASDGXXX.XXX.XXX.XXXFSDGHSFSDFDSFHSF
!'^%%&!'+!'+^%&!SDBSDFXXX.XXX.XXX.XXXSADASFSA
ASGFGD XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ASDSAFASFDASSADSA
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/wCn7AK/1)