# Parse string with variable length

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have a string of variable length, which include different IPs and it can be in this form:

`\"000.000.000.000\"`

or this form:

`\"000.000.000.000, 111.111.111.111\"`

I would like to come up with a way to be able to parse the first IP without knowing beforehand if the string includes only one IP or more. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: you want to extract 000.000.000.000 ?

Comment: @minattosama Yes

Comment: doesn't just a text.split(",")[0] work for you ?

Comment: @minattosama's answer is best, but you can also use python `re.search` to get only the first occurrence of a particular regex.

Comment: text.split(",")[0].strip('"')

Comment: @minattosama There is also a space in the beginning of the string, which is something that I do not know what to do about. Also the quotes are two and not one. The string that I have put is without the initial quotes, namely the initial string is `" \"000.000.000.000\"" `.

Comment: Then perhaps `text.split(',')[0].strip(' "')`

Comment: Does this help? [Regex: how to extract only first IP address from string (in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654285/regex-how-to-extract-only-first-ip-address-from-string-in-python) - [demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBVkE9RsnAwEAPCesoGBoa6iHhGCV1rszcgvyiEoWiVK6Cosy8Eo2iVL3i1MSi5AyNIvVoA13LWG0Ne6sYPQhTs9q4Vl1HoVhTL70ov7RAQ1Pz/38A)

Comment: @bobblebubble congrats on your gold regex badge! :)

Comment: I hope to join you one day...

Comment: @Nick I see, you carry a lot of preasures  already! :)

Comment: @bobblebubble you can never have too many! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I would choose regex for this.
It handles most of your cases, you don't have to care about the surrounding noise like spaces or slashes and you can loop through the result.

```
import re


def verify_ip(ip_address: str) -> bool:
    ip_segments = ip_address.split('.')
    if len(ip_segments) != 4:
        return False
    for segment in [int(ip_segment) for ip_segment in ip_segments]:
        if not 0 < segment < 255:
            return False
    return True


raw_string = '\"0156165100.000.000.000,111.111.111.111,192.168.1.1.10.15 1 68 3+- 41as asdfvyxcv 10.10.10.10\"'
pattern = r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'
matches = re.findall(pattern, raw_string)
for ip in matches:
    print(f'{ip if verify_ip(ip) else "bad ip"}')
```

**Result:**

```
bad ip
111.111.111.111
192.168.1.1
10.10.10.10
```

Comment: This would match `12356345.34578348753.23487234.287342735`

Comment: yes it would, is this a problem?

Comment: Well, that's not a valid IP address...

Comment: I would not use regex to verify the ip, but to get a pattern that I can process from there on. Parsing the ip is another story, but I added a function to my answer to show what I mean.